# How to use a generic sed command?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed, sh

I am having a file named test.js.

the content of the test.js can be dynamic . It can be the following.

```
   export default function () {
      http.get("http://@@NODE_IP@@:@@NODE_PORT@@/SccTestService/v1/id");
    }
```

or it can be as below . (The ip address and port can change.)

```
export default function () {
  http.get("http://172.19.32.1:30331/SccTestService/v1/id");
}
```

In my program i receive a test.js file. i want to replace the ip address and port with another ip address and port. How can I achieve this .
Basically I want to combine the following scenario.

```
IP=172.15.33.101
HTTP_PORT=32231

scenario 1.
sed -i -e "s/@@NODE_IP@@/$IP/g" test.js
sed -i -e "s/@@NODE_PORT@@/$HTTP_PORT/g" test.js

scenario 2 .( Note the IP address and port can change. In this example i am using 172.19.32.1 and 30331. )

sed -i -e "s/172.19.32.1/$IP/g" test.js
sed -i -e "s/30331/$HTTP_PORT/g" test.js
```

How can I, use generic sed command to handle all cases ?

In short the

sed should be able to replace `@@NODE_IP@@` or any other provided IP address in the file .
Also another generic sed command to replace the `@@NODE_PORT@@` or any other port number with a provided one . The solution should aims to use regex preferably

appreciate your help
thank you

Comment: `sed -i -e "s/@@NODE_IP@@/$IP/g" -e "s/172\.19\.32\.1/$IP/g" test.js`? Or `sed -i -E -e "s/(@@NODE_IP@@|172\.19\.32\.1/$IP/g" test.js`? (Note that a dot in a sed regular expression represents any character; escape it with a backslash to interpret it literally).

Comment: the problem is the IP address  172.19.32.1  will change. so i cant hard code it in the sed command

Comment: OK, so how do you know which IP address/port to replace in your file? Is there only one? Please add this information in your answer, not in comments.

Comment: Why don't you pass the IP address either on the command line, or in the environment, or via a configuration file - whatever is most convenient to you?

Comment: @RenaudPacalet The IP address and Port to replace in the file is available as variable IP & HTTP_PORT

Comment: No, these are the replacements. My question is about the IP address/port you want to replace in your original file. How do you know where they are?

Comment: It should be between http:/// in the file.

Comment: This looks like a [tag:k6] test. Why don't you provide the IP and port via environment variables and read the values from `__ENV`? Using the environment sounds a lot more robust than using `sed` to modify your test file

Comment: @knittl yes this k6 test. i am using k6 is running as kubernetes pod. i havent tried that __ENV option , maybe i could try that in the future during refactoring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use extended regular expressions (-E) in your case:
`sed -i -E -e "s@//[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+){3}@//$IP@" -e "s@:[0-9]{2,5}/@:$HTTP_PORT/@" test.js`

Let's decompose the command just in case:

- `sed -i -E` tells `sed` to edit the file and use extended regex.
- `-e "s@//[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+){3}@//$IP@"` looks for two slashed followed by a number with any amount of digits, followed by a group (repeated 3 times) composed of a dot followed by a number with any amount of digits. Technically, that would also match `//7658.0214.1245147.124369` but it shouldn't be an issue here.
- `-e "s@:[0-9]{2,5}/@:$HTTP_PORT/@"` looks for a number having between 2 and 5 digits, between two dots and a slash. This should avoid false positives in case your URL itself is subject to change, matching only a group of numbers would also match parts of the IP address.

I used `@` as the separator to avoid escaping slashes. I also avoided adding back-references and used two expressions because that matches your tests, but it could be put together into a single expression with the added benefit of being sure you're matching an IP address followed by a port.

Here's what the command to match an already defined IP and port would look like:
`sed -i -E -e "s@//[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+){3}:[0-9]+/@//$IP:$HTTP_PORT/@" test.js`

I removed the strict checking on the amount of digits for the port, but kept the leading slashes in case you ever call an API that takes an IP and a port as a path parameter.

Finally, we can add your scenario #1 to the command as a second expression, which doesn't need to be as strict since you use what appears to be a pattern. We don't have to separate IP and port either since they're supposed to be together.

Here's what I believe is the final command:
`sed -i -E -e "s@//[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+){3}:[0-9]+/@//$IP:$HTTP_PORT/@" -e "s/@@NODE_IP@@:@@NODE_PORT@@/$IP:$HTTP_PORT/" test.js`

Hope it helps, don't hesitate if you need any clarification.

Comment: But will this case regex address this scenarion .  http.get("http://@@NODE_IP@@:@@NODE_PORT@@/SccTestService/v1/id"); I could see @@NODE_IP@@ and @@NODE_PORT@@ are not replaced with the your solution. thank you

Comment: I misunderstood the question sorry, I didn't catch you wanted to merge scenario 1 and scenario 2. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Excellent !!!!!!!!!!!!! thank you . Good work

Answer (score 2):

Using any sed:

```
$ sed "s#\(http://\)\([^:]*\):\([^/]*\)#\1$IP:$HTTP_PORT#" test.js
export default function () {
    http.get("http://172.15.33.101:32231/SccTestService/v1/id");
}

export default function () {
    http.get("http://172.15.33.101:32231/SccTestService/v1/id");
}
```

The above was run on this input file:

```
$ cat test.js
export default function () {
    http.get("http://@@NODE_IP@@:@@NODE_PORT@@/SccTestService/v1/id");
}

export default function () {
    http.get("http://172.19.32.1:30331/SccTestService/v1/id");
}
```

after setting:

```
$ IP=172.15.33.101
$ HTTP_PORT=32231
```